# creating a dict based on two python dicts

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have two python dicts:

```
payload = {"key1":{"a":"1"},"key2":{"b":"2","c":"3"}}
```

and

```
data = {"1":"John","2":"Jacob"}
```

I would like my output to be:

```
{"key1":{"a":"John"},"key2":{"b":"Jacob","c":""}}
```

Any method that I try correctly prints the values, but does not update the output dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this using `dict comprehension` :

```
payload = {"key1":{"a":"1"},"key2":{"b":"2","c":"3"}}
data = {"1":"John","2":"Jacob"}

final = {k: {i:data[j] if j in data.keys() else "" for i, j in payload[k].items()} for k in payload}
print(final)
```

Output:

```
{'key2': {'b': 'Jacob', 'c': ''}, 'key1': {'a': 'John'}}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this.  It works like a charm...  But how would dict comprehension work when the data dict is complex as well?  Like for instance how would it work if data = {"key3":{"1":"John"},"key4":{"2":"Jacob"}}

Comment: Well, if the data are `{"key3":{"1":"John"},"key4":{"2":"Jacob"}}` you can map through the data values or you can group the values of each dict by their keys than process their data.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single method for this I am aware of, but you can use:

```
for k, v in payload.viewitems():
   payload[k] = {}
   for kv, vv in v.viewitems():
      payload[k][kv] = data.get(vv, "")
```

if you then inspect `payload` it has the contents you are after:

`{'key2': {'c': '', 'b': 'Jacob'}, 'key1': {'a': 'John'}}`